# Jinja2 Exception Handling

Tags: python, templates, exception, django-templates, jinja2

Is there a way to handle exceptions within a template in jinja2?

```
{% for item in items %}
   {{ item|urlencode }}  <-- item contains a unicode string that contains a character causes urlencode to throw KeyError
{% endfor %}
```

How do I handle that exception so that I can just skip that item or handle it without forcing the entire template rendering to fail?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a `{% try %}` in jinja (or equivalent).  As far as I see it, your options are to write an exception safe version of `urlencode` and use that as your filter, or to sanitize the input before passing it to jinja2.

Comment: +1 on sanitizing the list of items before passing it on to Jinja

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
{% for item in items %}
   {{ item | custom_urlencode_filter }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then in whatever file you have setting up your jinja2 environment

```
def custom_urlencode_filter(value):
    try:
        return urlencode(value)
    except:
        # handle the exception


environment.filters['custom_urlencode_filter'] = custom_urlencode_filter
```

More on [custom jinja2 filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#writing-filters)

Comment: Thanks for explaining it more in a detailed way. This is the better answer! :)

Comment: An alternative to the `environment.filters` is to pass the function to your template. In the route: `return render_template('yourpage.html', custom_urlencode_filter=custom_urlencode_filter)` and in the template: `{{ custom_urlencode_filter(item) }}`

Answer (score 6):

While jinja2 does not have a way to handle this by default, there is a workaround.

Since `try` is not supported in the template language, we need a helper function defined in Python, like this:

```
def handle_catch(caller, on_exception):
    try:
         return caller()
    except:
         return on_exception
```

This method is injected into the template engine, either via the `Environment.globals` or when calling the render method. In this example it is injected via the render method.

```
my_template.render(handle_catch=handle_catch)
```

In the template itself it is then possible to define a macro:

```
{% macro catch(on_exception) %}
    {{ handle_catch(caller, on_exception) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

And this can then be used as:

```
{% for item in items %}
   {% call catch('') %}
       {{ item | custom_urlencode_filter }}
   {% endcall %}
{% endfor %}
```

Notes:

- The caller method is provided by the jinja2, and this is a function that renders the code between `{% call ... %}` and `{% endcall %}`
- on_exception can be used to provide an alternative text in case of exceptions, but in this case we just use an empty string.

Answer (score -6):

There's none. Just handle the exceptions within the urlencode filter function.