# Jinja2 loop on hosts from a group failing when one node of this group is down

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

I have this piece of code

```yaml
---
- name: gather facts
  hosts: all

- hosts: proxy

  tasks:

    - blockinfile:
        path: /etc/example
        block: |
          {% for n in groups['all'] %}
          {{ hostvars[n]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}
          {% endfor %}
```

if one node from the group `all` is down, the Jinja2 loop is failing.

I did not find a solution to prevent that (tried with `skip_unreachable: true` without success for instance). Off course I can comment the down node in the inventory but this is neither convenient nor reliable.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Jinja does not directly do exception handling, but you may use an auxiliary function to do so. Then either pass the function to your `render_template()` call, or add it as a filter to your Jinja environment. More detail in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763226/42346

Comment: Have you tried using the conditional for loop: `{% for n in groups['all'] if 'ansible_default_ipv4' in hostvars[n] %}`? Alternatively, if you still wish to process `n` or provide some default value, the `.get` syntax is for you: `hostvars[n].get('ansible_default_ipv4', {}).get('address', 'SOME DEFAULT HERE')`

Comment: thanks @mdaniel for the advice, this is the kind of solution I was expecting (I wanted to have something handled natively by ansible) but that can be a workaround, despite being a little bit overkill.