# Jinja2 default filter stacking problems with number fields

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to lay out a report which list many temperatures - some of which may not exist.
The temps need to be rounded to 1 decimal and subtracted from each other.

```
<tr>
    <td>Average temp</td>
    <td>{{ v.previous_temp|default('')|round(1) }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.temp|default('')|round(1) }}</td>
    <td>{{ (v.temp - v.previous_temp)|default('')|round() }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Trouble is Jinja still blows up if it sees a missing temp when I try to default to '' since it is trying to do math on a string variable.
Setting to a number would fix this but then I would be displaying bad data.

Is there a way to set a 'math proof' default or perhaps a 'stop filtering' filter so the the rounds are not even tried if defaulted?

I know I can do this with **{% if temp in v % }** wrappers but with all the variables I have, that will make for a messy template!

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

why do not test a default variable not in range temperature?:

```
<tr>
    {% if ((v.previous_temp|default(-1000)) != -1000) and ((v.temp|default(-1000)) != -1000) %} 
    <td>Average temp</td>
    <td>{{ v.previous_temp|round(1) }}</td>
    <td>{{ v.temp|round(1) }}</td>
    <td>{{ (v.temp - v.previous_temp)|round() }}</td>
    {% endif %}
 </tr>
```

Comment: I thought about this one but any  magic number will not work because I am subtracting. If I set bad number to 999999 then if BOTH temps are missing 999999 - 999999 = 0 which is a valid temp!

Comment: sorry i misunderstand something, in my sample the both have to be correct else no substraction...so i dont see where is your problem or you have to show more code

Comment: You are right - still the code is just as verbose as {% if ('prev_min_temp' in v)  and ('min_temp' in v) %}. I am looking for something cleaner. This looks promising https://stackoverflow.com/a/58434921/7654773