# Jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html error

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to make a website back-end in VS Code using Flask and Python. I'm stuck with trying to render my HTML file on the server. Now I'm getting this error:

```
File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "c:\Users\лена\Documents\Б\Second library site back-end\website\views.py", line 7, in home
    return render_template("home.html")
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 146, in render_template
    template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 126, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 62, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html
```

Here is what my directory structure looks like, theres a folder called templates and 2 html files within it:

[image: File Structure]

Here's my `main.py` file:

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's my `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(__name__):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'i love bananas'

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint (views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint (auth, url_prefix='/')

    return app
```

Here's my `views.py` file:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

Here's my home.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% block title %}TheAkashicLibrary{% endblock %}
```

After searching for answers, it seems there must be an error in the structure of the directory, but it appears that everything is correct. I followed Tech with Tim's flask website tutorial, so everything should be right, but it's not working. [Here's a link to the video I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI&t=2217s).

Comment: video tutorials are great, but you need to understand the docs too and not just copy exactly for these reasons. the error refers to `jinja2.exceptions`

Comment: @D.L Yes, the error refers to `jinja2.exceptions`... so what?  Is that supposed to tell us something? What is the meaning you're trying to convey here?

Comment: I see that `main.py` is not at the same directory level as the other code -- it does not appear to be inside the `website` directory.  Is that intentional?

Comment: try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692387/jinja2-exception-handling

Comment: Yes, this is the way it was done in the tutorial

Comment: @D.L That link refers to errors that happen _inside_ of a template.  That is not the situation here...

Comment: Can you edit the post to include the contents of `base.html`? Your code is correct, and the file structure is correct, so the issue is in that file.

Comment: To see this for yourself, remove the line `{% extends "base.html" %} ` and the page should render successfully.

Comment: I tried removing that line and only left {% block title %}TheAkashicLibrary{% endblock %} in home.html. I reran main.py and it still gives the same error

Comment: That's interesting. I copied and pasted your code and ran it on my machine and it works for me.

Comment: What could possibly be the issue here? Did something get installed incorrectly? Could something have gotten corrupted? I don't know where to look anymore, how do I fix this?

Comment: It's possible that you're running old packages, you can check your version numbers with `pip list`. That's the only thing I could think of.

Comment: Try ```Blueprint('views', __name__, template_folder="templates") ``` [see reference](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/#templates)